# List with functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

I am trying to make a list of functions from where I can randomly pull one of the functions. I've tried several methods, both trying to make it actively select the second function in the list and just trying to make it random. Both fail.

The list works fine if it has text instead of functions in it.
`q = [opt1(), opt2(), opt3()]` also activates the function despite me not calling on them.

How do I  make it so that it randomly pulls one of the functions from the list?

```
import random

def opt1():
    print("hej1")

def opt2():
    print("hej2")

def opt3():
    print("hej3")

q = [opt1(), opt2(), opt3()]

health = "100"
p = "1"
print("you have ", p, " potions")
print("Your health is ", health,)
while True:
    a = input("A =")
    if a == "add":
        health = int(health)
        p = int(p) + 1
        print("you have ", p, " potions")
        print("Your health is ", health,)
        a = input("A =")
    if a == "fight":
        q[1]
        #random.choice(q)
```

Comment: *"activates the function despite me not calling on them"* – `opt1()` *is* a function call.

Comment: You call the function as soon as you put brackets behind it. Therefore, just put the function name in your list.

Comment: Why do you think you aren't calling them?

Comment: put function names in list and call them when they get selected.

Comment: .. and call it with `q[1]()` - you have to figure out how to provide parameters to your function as well if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly adjust your list q to this:

```
q = [opt1, opt2, opt3]
```

Otherwise you are already calling the functions.

Then I suggest that you define an index:

```
ind = random.randint(0,len(q)-1)
```

This selects a random function from the list.
Now the only thing left to do is put brackets behind it:

`q[ind]()`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to remove the `()`s when you're adding the functions to the list. So this line is the problem:

```
q = [opt1(), opt2(), opt3()]
```

by including the `()` what you're doing is calling the function and adding the result of the function call to the list, rather than adding the function itself to the list. This code below should be roughly what you need

```
import random

def opt1():
    print("hej1")

def opt2():
    print("hej2")

def opt3():
    print("hej3")

q = [opt1, opt2, opt3]
randomFunction = random.choice (q)
randomFunction()
```